# Red error under-squiggle when assigning int a {0}

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am writing a C++ program and VS Code shows an error red squiggle for

```
int a{0};
```

so it seems to me the default syntax checking is based on an older C++ standard. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this all of the code? Just a single file with `int a{0};`? If so, you're probably right. If not, make sure there's nothing that could be confusing intellisence into ratting out the wrong line.

Comment: @user4581301 I just singled out this line that's causing the problem, but this is not the only line in the file. But I do suspect VS Code is basing on an older C++ standard, and I don't know how to check where this setting is made nor how to change it.